# Upgrading to Elastic Search NEST 7.0.1 breaks code that checks if an index exists

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, nest, nuget-update

After upgrading Elastic Search NEST from 7.0.0-alpha2 to 7.0.1, I am no longer able to use the IndexExistsAsync method in Nest.ElasticClient.

According to the documentation, the method is removed and is a breaking change, so I changed the call to ElasticClient.Indices.ExistsAsync as follows:

**Old code:**

```
var existsResponse = await _elasticClient.IndexExistsAsync(model.Name);
```

**New code:**

```
var existsResponse = await _elasticClient.Indices.ExistsAsync(model.Name);
```

And with new code I get the following response, which is not really helpful in finding and fixing the issue:

```
Invalid NEST response built from a successful (404) low level call on HEAD: /12-e449636ee7e1eb1343414698c95ce1e1

Audit trail of this API call:
- [1] HealthyResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.1208228

Request:

Request stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.

Response:

Response stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.
```

Setting the `connectionSettings.DisableDirectStreaming(true);` did not help and I get the exact same response.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What response do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

I think the message you see tells you everything.

```
Invalid NEST response built from a successful (404) low level call on HEAD: /12-e449636ee7e1eb1343414698c95ce1e1
```

`response built from a successful` - elasticsearch call was successful, but status 404 (not exists) was returned and mapped to `existsResponse.Exists` which is `false` in this case. There is no additional request/response information attached, this is why you see:

```
Request:

Request stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.

Response:

Response stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.
```

Same behavior when you try to do it via kibana:

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:

When testing following code with elasticsearch 7.2.0 and NEST 7.0.1

```
var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);              

await client.Indices.CreateAsync("documents");                   
var exists = await client.Indices.ExistsAsync("documents");      
Console.WriteLine($"Index created, exists?: {exists.Exists}");   

await client.Indices.DeleteAsync("documents");                   
exists = await client.Indices.ExistsAsync("documents");          
Console.WriteLine($"Index deleted, exists?: {exists.Exists}");
```

prints

```
Index created, exists?: True
Index deleted, exists?: False
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: As you correctly pointed out, the HTTP Response from ES tells me that the index does not exist (404). What I did not mention in my question was that the rest of my code relies on a properly populated NEST response object and I check for the IsValid property to continue with index creation or return. And in cases where the index exists, I still get an IsValid=false and Exists=false. It seems that the 7.0.1 clients (both high level and low level) do not populate the response object correctly and ES needs to fix them.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Just tested it with NEST 7.0.1 and still works correctly. Are you sure you are using NEST 7.x against elasticsearch 7.x?

Comment: I am using NEST 7.0.1 against a local docker container of ElasticSearch 7.2.0. The code you provided works, but not when I reverse the order and first run the ExistsAsync!

Answer (score 0):

The same problem here. After upgrade to Nest 7 (both 7.0.0 and 7.0.1) against an ElasticSearch cluster with version 7.2.0 we get the following message:

Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful (502) low level call on HEAD: /leads_2019.07

## Audit trail of this API call:

- [1] BadResponse: Node: http://xxx:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.1931249

  ## OriginalException: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: Request failed to execute. Call: Status code 502 from: HEAD /leads_2019.07

We get the same error against a cluster with version 6.8.1